# Passing integers to JSX attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```html
return <textarea className="tox-input" rows=2 ></textarea>;
```

I want to pass `rows=2` to this tag. However, this results in the following error.

```
Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.
```

After a bit of research, I couldn't find a way to solve this. Please could someone tell me the proper way to do it in JSX?

Note: Using `rows={2}` doesn't give an error, but it only shows one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use curly brace:

```
return <textarea className="tox-input" rows={2} ></textarea>;
```

It will pass integer.

[Playground area](https://codesandbox.io/s/cra-forked-oe2ty?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I mentioned in the question that that didn't work.

Comment: In the devtools, this is passed through as a string.

Comment: Dear @DillonBarnes, it definitely works, maybe your code has a problem somewhere else

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't notice that I had a limiting `height` in the CSS.

Comment: and you don't even need to pass rows as the default is 2 rows

Comment: @MWO I was using 2 as an example. I want it bigger than that. But thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Using rows={2} is the right call. Look for any css rule that limits the max height of the textarea or a parent element that does this.

Comment: Thanks. I had a `height` CSS rule that I missed.

Comment: Glad I helped, mark as answer if it indeed helped you.

Comment: Sorry, but I gave it to AmerllicA as that was posted first. I did upvote your post though.